# Kia Pregio Van 2004 fuse problem

Tags: kia

So I replaced the battery in this van, I know the new battery is fine because I've tested it. i think I remember some sparks when i started to put it in, so I'm pretty sure that i touched the terminals/leads the wrong way around for a second or two.

Now, the dash lights come on, but absolutely nothing happens when i turn the key. So I guess I've blown some fuse or other, but I can't work out where, All the large fuses under the seat are fine and all the smaller ones in the little panel by the driver's knee are ok too. I've got the exact same van which is running fine and I've tried removing each fuse to see if it has the same effect, but nothing does.

Are there some other fuses somewhere which I've missed or have I blown something more serious? I can't take it to an electrician (apart from i don't want to because I've spent waay too much on this van already), because it's not registered, and obviously, it won't start.

I tried to roll start it the other day and I'm pretty sure that didn't work either, although I need to try again.

Anyone with specific knowledge of the set-up of these vans, or the likely damage I've caused?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Why did you replace the battery? Was it because it would not start? It would be a good idea to check the fuses with a multimeter. Sometimes the visual inspection does not reveal the defect. Also, keep in mind that you may have damaged the computer by accidentally reversing the polarity.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I replaced it because the battery was dead after leaving the van sitting for too long, it won't hold a charge, but i know the replacement battery is ok I don't know how to check the fuses (although I'm sure I could look it up!) but like I said, I've removed all the fuses in the identical van, one by one, and none of them prevented that van from starting, which indicates to me that that isn't where the problem is.

To correct my original post, it is possible to start the van by rolling it, and it runs fine once it's started.

Comment: What you said about the computer could be correct, or as I suggested, a different fuse, or wiring that's shorted. I just don't know where to go from here, what to check, or how

Comment: So, you were able to start it before. The starter is not typically run thru a regular fuse. It will be run thru a relay. Those are the larger square box looking things in the fuse box. Many vehicles today have more than one fuse box, one in the cabin and one in the engine compartment. Did you check both boxes?

Comment: Hi, yes, there is a panel of mostly small fuses in the cabin, those are the ones where I've removed every single one. Then there are 5 larger fuses in a box by the engine. They are labelled, and the only relevant one would be the one labelled 'main' and an autoelectrician told me that it isn't broken.

Comment: So that was the reason for my original post - having eliminated those two collections of fuses, I don't know where else to look. So a relay is still an easily removable part? Just a bigger box fuse? Are there other fusible parts which would be harder to get to?